Legend title showing without items in ArcGIS Pro layout
I have not been able to find any answers to this question on ESRI's help pages or other forum sites. It feels pretty simple. I have a map series with different zones in a county and the three legend items "Featured Zone, Neighboring Zones, and Other Zones" will be on the legend for each map series. Thus, I want to keep them all in one column. However, ArcGIS Pro won't allow me to have a legend with one column of 3 items and a column with one item, so when the boundary of another county (in this instance Monterey) is shown, the "Other Zones" item would move to the right so there were 2 columns with 2 items each. Thus, I created a second legend which only has the other counties visible (4 in total, but no more than 3 are ever shown) so my zones legend wouldn't be adjusted, which is the below image.
[
When no counties are shown, I'd like for the legend to just not be seen, but for whatever reason the title Legend 1 keeps showing up. If I uncheck the visibility on the legend that won't remove it properly, as it also removes it for map pages that need the content of this legend. I'm trying to figure out how I can just make the legend invisible entirely (including the "Legend 1" box) when it isn't needed. I'm not sure why the "sync with layer visibility" button doesn't apply to making the title and such disappear.

Has anyone had a similar issue? I tried to convert the Zone legend to graphics and then just operate with one legend for the counties, but that still had the same issue. I'm not experienced with coding for layouts so if there's a solution there, please point me in the right direction.
For reference I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.0 (I can't update on a work computer).

I explored this and I too cannot make the legend name invisible in Layout. But have you actually tried exporting to pdf/png? It does not appear in the export...

Ah, you're right! Odd that it disappears then, but can't be removed elsewhere. Thanks so much!
